# Torsion and inverse limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, torsion-groups

Given a countable family of (non-abelian) torsion groups $G_n$ (i.e. each element has a finite order) in an inverse system
$G_1\leftarrow G_2\leftarrow\dots G_n\leftarrow\dots$, where the maps are assumed to be surjective and given that the inverse limit $G=\lim_\leftarrow G_n$ is torsion,  can we derive that the set of these groups has some uniform bound $L$ on their orders, i.e. that, for all but finitely many n, $G_n^L=1$.

I do not know the answer but I believe that it is a "yes".

Comment: I don't think so. In the case when the groups $G_n$ are all equal, and the maps are all the identity map, then $G \cong G_n$. Maybe you want to assume that the individual $G_n$ all have bounded torsion?

Comment: OK, @Derek, perhaps one can rephrase to say that the inverse system is not almost (eventually) constant.